# JS - convert an array to a multi-level object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, replace

I've been on this for the 4th day.

Need

```
const base = [
    { "rel": 1, "title": "a", "path": "AAA" },
    { "rel": 2, "title": "b", "path": "AAA/BBB" },
    { "rel": 3, "title": "c", "path": "AAA/BBB/CCC" },
    { "rel": 4, "title": "d", "path": "AAA/BBB/DDD" },
    { "rel": 5, "title": "e", "path": "AAA/CCC" },
    { "rel": 6, "title": "f", "path": "BBB" }]
```

convert to:

```
{
    "a": {
        "rel": 1,
        "b": {
            "rel": 2,
            "c": {"rel": 3},
            "d": {"rel": 4}
        },
        "e": {"rel": 5}
    },
    "f": {"rel": 6}
}
```

my code before:

```
console.log(start(base));

function start(arr, index = 0, lvl = 0, res = {}) {
    let { rel, title, path } = arr[index];

    path = path.split("/");
    const how = path.length;
    let lvlNext = null; if (arr[index + 1]) { lvlNext = arr[index + 1].path.split("/"); lvlNext = lvlNext.length; }

    if (how == lvl) res = { rel }

    if (how > lvl) res[title] = start(arr, index, lvl + 1, res[title]);

    if (lvlNext && how == lvl) return start(arr, index + 1, lvl, res);

    return res
}
```

It makes the most sense to do it by "recurse", but I fail to return to the top later (possibly even a few)

PS. Sorry i don't write in english

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The update to the question necessitated a rewrite of the code required to manipulate the input array into the required output object.

Here's a demonstration of concept for you.

I start by sorting the input array by path to avoid getting lower level elements before higher ones.

I then build a map of the required layout using the path data in each array element, incorporating the `title` and `rel` properties. This made it much easier to keep track of where the various data fitted in the emerging tree. The `buildMap()` function works along the path attribute, calling itself to complete each lower level.

Once the map is built it's straightforward to recurse down the tree to create the required objects and strip out the path data. This is the `buildFinal()` function.

**Note:** This code has only been run on the sample data supplied. You should test it on a larger sample before using it in earnest.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Recursion again</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    (function(){
        "use strict";
        console.log("IIFE executing");


        /**
         * Using the path property of each element, create an object of the right
         * structure. This is necessary since without the path information we can lose
         * track of where we are in the tree
         */
        function buildMap(map, el) {
            // console.log("Processing path; "+el.path);
            let path = el.path.split('/');
            if (path.length) {
                let currentNode = path[0];
                if (path.length === 1) {
                    map.subs = map.subs || {};
                    map.subs[currentNode] = {rel: el.rel, title: el.title}
                } else {
                    if (map.subs[currentNode]) {
                        // Remove the first element from the path and update the element
                        el.path = path.slice(1).join('/');
                        // Call ourselves from where we are.
                        buildMap(map.subs[currentNode],el);
                    } else {
                        throw `Invalid path ${el.path}`
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw 'No path in element.';
            }
            // console.log(map);
        }

        /**
         * Now recurse the map, extracting the title and rel information to create
         * the required properties in the right places.
         */
        function buildFinal(map, obj) {
            if (map.title) {
                obj.rel = map.rel
            }
            if (map.subs) {
                for (const [path, el] of Object.entries(map.subs)) {
                    obj[el.title] = buildFinal(el, {});
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }

        function sortByPath($arr) {
            return $arr.sort((el1, el2)=>{
                if (el1.path > el2.path) return 1;
                return (el1.path === el2.path?0:-1);
            })
        }
        const base = [
            { "rel": 1, "title": "a", "path": "AAA" },
            { "rel": 2, "title": "b", "path": "AAA/BBB" },
            { "rel": 3, "title": "c", "path": "AAA/BBB/CCC" },
            { "rel": 4, "title": "d", "path": "AAA/BBB/DDD" },
            { "rel": 5, "title": "e", "path": "AAA/CCC" },
            { "rel": 6, "title": "f", "path": "BBB" }]

        // Sort the base array by path to ensure that we get higher elements before lower ones.
        sortByPath(base);
        // console.log(base);

        // Working from the path included in each element, build a map object that places
        // all the data in the right place
        let pathMap = {};
        base.forEach(function(el) {
            buildMap(pathMap, el);
        });

        console.log("Finished building map");
        // console.log(pathMap);

        // Now with the map built we can recurse down it to build the final object
        let finalObject = buildFinal(pathMap, {});
        console.log("Finished building final object");
        console.log(finalObject);
    })();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

I will try to transform it into my project

Comment: Yes - I missed that. It should be easy enough to fix. I'll leave that to you, but ping me if you have trouble.

Comment: I gave a wrong example, you need to navigate in the "path"

Comment: I'll update the code here if you post a corrected example.

Comment: @Atomos672 I've reworked the code to handle your revised sample data. Please see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14853083/tangentially-perpendicular)